# Байтовое представление символа

Tags: java, кодировка, utf-8

Хочу написать функцию считывания из файла байтов, которая будет возвращать массив байтов (byte[])
Потом в этом массиве я хочу заменить все "символы перехода на новую строку"(В десятичном представлении они имеют код(10)) на "символы конца строки \0"(в десятичном представлении - 0).

Содержимое файла Test.txt:

```
Hello
World!
```

Написал код:

```
//Считывание из файла
byte[] read_file(String file_name) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] cbuf = null;
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try 
        {
            fin = new FileInputStream(path + '/' + file_name);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            cbuf = new byte[bis.available()];
            fin.read(cbuf, 0, bis.available());
            bis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (fin != null)
                    fin.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e2)
            {
                System.out.println("Object " + file_name + " was not created: " + e2.toString());
            }
        }
        return cbuf;
    }
```

Потом делаю в main(например):

```
    byte[] bytes = read_file("Some_file.example"); 
    System.out.println("Before: "); 
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) 
       System.out.print(bytes[i] + " "); 
    System.out.println(); 

    //Напечетали символы
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) 
       System.out.print((char)bytes[i]); 
    System.out.println();
```

Результат:

```
Before: 
72 101 108 108 111 13 10 87 111 114 108 100 33
Hello
World!



 //Заменили символ перевода строки на символ конца строки 
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) 
       if (bytes[i] == (byte)10) 
           bytes[i] = (byte)0; 

    System.out.println("After: "); 
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) 
       System.out.print(bytes[i]); 

    System.out.println(); 
    //Напечетали символы
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) 
       System.out.print((char)bytes[i] + " ");


Результат после изменения массива байтов:
After: 
72 101 108 108 111 13 0 87 111 114 108 100 33 
Hello
 World!
```

В итоге результат: Содержимое файла по-прежнему печатается так как ему хочется, плюс ко всему добавляется еще пробел на новой строке.
Как такое может быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Before:  72 101 108 108 111 **13 10** 87 111 114 108 100 33

Символ перевода строки в Windows состоит на самом деле из двух: перевод строки (10) + перевод каретки на начало строки (13). В данном случае у вас как раз удаляется только один из этих символов. Дальше, надеюсь, сами додумаете :)

[Перевод строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.92_ASCII)

**UPD.**

Хочу добавить ещё, что есть отличный метод

```
System.lineSeparator()
```

Возвращает системно-зависимую строку - перевод строки для текущей ОС.

Comment: хорошо. Как тогда выглядит этот же символ в Linux?

Comment: Я же в конце ответа ссылку предоставил

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` - это не самый лучший вариант. Просто потому что все чаще приходится работать с файлами, которые "сделаны" в другой ОС. Также есть форматы файлов, которые устанавливают свой перевод строки, независимый от ОС.

Comment: Для данной конкретной задачи лучше не завязываться на системный формат - а считать переводом строки любую последовательность из 4х возможных (10, 13, 10 13 или 13 10)